# MySQL.sock doesn't exist | CentOS7 - ERPNext installation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql.sock, erpnext

I'm trying to install ERPNext with their install script provided at github (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frappe/bench/master/install_scripts/setup_frappe.sh) on my virtual CentOS 7 server. It has MariaDB 10.x installed and I have to remove it first, before I use the script, otherwise I get an error.

But I don't have a solution for following problem, could you guys help me out?

```
sudo bash setup_frappe.sh --setup-production
Installing for centos 7 amd64
In case you encounter an error, you can post on https://discuss.frappe.io

Adding centos mariadb repo
Installing packages for centos. This might take time...
Installing wkhtmltopdf
Configuring CentOS services
Starting services
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Comment: what command you executed so getting this error...

Comment: @ZafarMalik https://github.com/frappe/bench/blob/master/install_scripts/setup_frappe.sh

Comment: Try changing the perms on that folder: `chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/`

Answer (score 0):

In Cmd try this:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
```